# Changing data type in a Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code

```
L = np.random.choice([-1,1], size = [2,2])

np.putmask(L, L == -1, "+")

print(L)
```

I get this error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'`
. Any solution for this problem.

Comment: Why do you want to put a string, "+" in a numeric array?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to convert all negative terms to positive.

The issue here is with your use of the 'np.putmask' function

From the documentation example:

```
>>> x = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
>>> np.putmask(x, x>2, x**2)
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 9, 16, 25]])
```

Hence, for your code to work you should use:

```
>>>L = np.random.choice([-1,1], size = [2,2])

>>>np.putmask(L, L == -1, np.abs(L))

>>>print(L)

[[1 1]
 [1 1]]
```

Now, if instead, what you actually want is to replace it by the symbol "+"
You have to change the dtype of the array.

Since np.random.choice works with a fixed input, it uses the same data type when building the random array!
Hence, , you can change it after its built, or change the input, like this:

```
L = np.random.choice([-1,1], size = [2,2])
L = np.array(L, dtype='object')
np.putmask(L, L == -1, "+")
```

or like that:

```
L = np.random.choice(np.array([-1,1],dtype='object'), size = [2,2])
np.putmask(L, L == -1, "+")

print(L)
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks this work. But I am trying to get symbol + not  '+' . Is there a way to get rid of these commas on top of symbol +.

Comment: the commas are there to show its a string. its not possible to have an operator in a matrix. A string, or byte, or other forms of objects are.

Comment: Python doesn't symbols in that sense.  There are strings, and there are operators (a kind of 'function'), but not a symbol.

Comment: Is dypte the only solution? There must be other way around to get + sign print out.

Comment: Is your focus on changing the values of items in an array, or on the display of such an array.  If it's a matter of display, I'd suggest modifying your question to show us exactly what you want to print.

Comment: a + is an operator. it cant exist by itself. "+" is a string. it can exist by itself.   its possible to transform a string into an operator, example: eval("1+2") >>> 3  but eval("+") >>> error, because the operator cant exist by itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [227]: np.random.choice([-1,1], size=[2,2])                                  
Out[227]: 
array([[ 1,  1],
       [-1,  1]])
```

Change the numbers to strings:

```
In [229]: x=np.random.choice(["-1","1"], size=[2,2])                            
In [230]: x                                                                     
Out[230]: 
array([['-1', '1'],
       ['-1', '-1']], dtype='<U2')
```

Note the dtype, 'U2'.  Now we can replace some of those strings with another string:

```
In [231]: np.putmask(x,x=="-1", '+')                                            
In [232]: x                                                                     
Out[232]: 
array([['+', '1'],
       ['+', '+']], dtype='<U2')
```

I could do string operations on elements of such an array:

```
In [233]: [''.join(row) for row in x.tolist()]                                  
Out[233]: ['+1', '++']
```